# Bash script: binary operator expected

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script

So I have reviewed a lot of entries on here and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here. I am new to scripting and want to know why this does not work:

input is

```
./filedirarg.sh /var/logs fileordir.sh
```

script is

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Running file or directory evaluation script"
LIST=$@
if [ -f $LIST ]
then
echo "The entry ${LIST} is a file"
elif [ -d $LIST ]
then
echo "The entry ${LIST} is a directory"
fi
```

This results in

```
./filedirarg.sh: line 4: [: /var/logs: binary operator expected
./filedirarg.sh: line 7: [: /var/logs: binary operator expected
```

It runs fine with this

```
./filedirarg.sh fileordir.sh
```

Quoting the `$LIST` in the evaluation results in no output except the first echo statement.

Comment: (1) Stupid question: you show a command that mentions two scripts, and then you show a script.  Which script are you showing?  I guess it’s obvious, but it’s better if you say. (2) Please describe what the script is supposed to do, rather than forcing us to read it and try to figure it out (given that you **know** that it’s wrong). (3) Have you posted the script accurately (e.g., by copy-and-paste) or did you just look at it and retype it?  `[ -f $LIST }` would cause an error (mismatched brackets). (4) Please indent your code intelligently.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (5) You need to learn how to debug. There are lots of resources for that here and elsewhere on the web. Simple things to try: `echo "$LIST"`, and add an `else` clause to your `if`.

Comment: Thanks for saying my question is stupid first off. Much appreciated when I am just starting out. Second, you can clearly see that filedirarg is the script being executed with another script name as one of the arguments being passed. I couldn't copy the script directly due to restricted access and had to type this out. The } is a typo. The script has ]. And elif should work fine and does with a file name instead of a directory. Not very helpful.

Comment: This addresses your comment under David's answer. I write it here because it has nothing to do with the answer. You wrote "`LIST=$@` accepts all args and works fine". No, it doesn't work fine. If you run `./script.sh a "b c"` then `"$@"` expands to two items and almost always this is what you want, `$@` expands to three items. Now take `LIST=$@`. Then `$LIST` expands to three items as well, `"$LIST"` expands to one item. Work with `"$@"`, rewriting to another name brings you trouble. Also [it's a good practice to name your variables in lowercase](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42849/108618).

Comment: So the reason I am doing variable names in upper case is that the instructor in the class I am taking literally said that it was best practice to write variable names in upper case. He is also where I got the idea of setting a variable to $@ to take in every argument instead of specifying them like $1 $2. I guess that is incorrect? And you are correct it is not needed. I was trying to expand LIST to 3 different items, then run each item through the evaluations. I am now more confused. :-(

Comment: `"$@"` is perfectly correct where you can pass multiple arguments. Sometimes you can't, like with your `test -f …` or so. My point is: there's no need to create another variable with the same content as `"$@"` because the content is not really the same. Check my updated answer to see there is `"$@"` used there but it's hidden under the default behavior of `for some_variable ; do`.

Comment: (1) I never meant to say that *your* question was stupid.  I see now that I wasn’t clear; I’m sorry about that.  I mean that, by asking you “Which script are you showing?”, ***I*** was asking a stupid question.  Because, yes, I can clearly see that `filedirarg` is the script being executed with another script name as one of the arguments — and I could also clearly see that line 4 said `[ -f $LIST }`; that which is obvious is not always true. I still believe that you should ***say*** that the script is `filedirarg.sh`, and/or change the `fileordir.sh` argument … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  to `an_unrelated_script.sh`, or, better yet, `a_plain_file`.  (2) I still strongly recommend that, when you ask a question like this, you describe what the script is supposed to do.  I’m still wondering what you were expecting to happen when you passed multiple arguments to a script that doesn’t have the capability to loop.  Given that your `if`-`then`-`elif` structure allows only one `echo` statement to execute, what output were you expecting?  (4) I repeat my request that you indent code to illuminate its structure. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  I’m disappointed that, even though you edited your question after you saw my comment(s), you fixed only the typo, and didn’t address the other issues. (5) When I suggested that you add an `else` I meant after the `echo "The entry ${LIST} is a directory"` statement. If you had gotten a message, `The entry /var/logs fileordir.sh is neither a file or a directory`, wouldn’t that have helped you to understand what was happening? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (11) I echo @Kamil’s advice to name your variables in lower case, but, if your instructor tells you to write variable names in upper case, then you should do that.  (12) If your instructor tells you to set a variable to `$@`, you should get a better instructor.  (13) You say (in [a comment](https://superuser.com/q/1239241/150988https#comment1815687_1239248) on [David’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1239241/150988#1239248), but addressed to me) that “`LIST=$@` accepts all args and works fine”. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  I invite (challenge) you to post a complete script that uses `LIST=$@` and does something useful, like doing something with each argument (individually). Setting `LIST` *and then never using it* doesn’t count.  `echo "$LIST"` doesn’t count. Check whether it works with names that contain spaces, like `Program files` or `shopping list`.

Answer (score 3):

I think `[ -f … ]` (or `test -f …`) requires exactly one argument. When you run

```
./filedirarg.sh /var/logs fileordir.sh
```

there are two. The same with `[ -d … ]`.

---

This is a quick fix:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Running file or directory evaluation script"

for file ; do
 if [ -f "$file" ]
 then
  echo "The entry '$file' is a file"
 elif [ -d "$file" ]
 then
  echo "The entry '$file' is a directory"
 fi
done
```

Thanks to quoting it should work with names with spaces (e.g. `./filedirarg.sh "file name with spaces"`).

Also note `for file ; do` is equivalent to `for file in "$@" ; do`.

Comment: There is also another more obvious error :)

Comment: @DavidPostill I know. I assumed it's a typo because if you actually run it with `}` it throws a different error.

Comment: The `for` line could be simplified to `for file; do`. Your `in` clause is the default when it is omitted.

Comment: @AFH Thank you. I've learnt something today. :)

Comment: Added the file=$@ at the top to accept the arguments. This works perfectly now. Thanks!

Comment: All the useful assistance is VERY much appreciated. Everyone here but Scott helped me expand my knowledge.

Comment: @seolchan "Added the `file=$@` at the top to accept the arguments." – Frankly it seems to make no sense. My script works for me without this modification.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - In passing, it is worth noting that going through an intermediate variable (`LIST` in the original question) will always cause problems when there are spaces in the file names. By going direct to the argument list, as you have done, preserves the spaces, though it is not obvious that you have solved this issue at the same time. I have not found a variant on `LIST="$@"` which preserves the correct file names on expansion, except by using an array: `list=("$@")`, then `for f in "${list[@]}" ...`. The questioner certainly has raised some interesting issues!

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - I see I have just crossed with your comment under the original question!

Answer (score 0):

#### binary operator expected

> if [ -f $LIST }

The `}` above should be a `]`, as explained by [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/):

```
$ shellcheck myscript

Line 4:
if [ -f $LIST }
^-- SC1009: The mentioned parser error was in this if expression.
   ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this test expression.
              ^-- SC1072: Expected test to end here (don't wrap commands in []/[[]]). Fix any mentioned problems and try again.

$
```

Comment: There is also another more obvious error: `LIST=$@`

Comment: Like I said above, that was a typo due to me having to write it out. Thanks though.

Comment: and Scott, LIST=$@ accepts all args and works fine ;-)

Comment: @seolchan Then next time please take care to copy and paste the code you actually using. Otherwise you are wasting our time :/